# Is it possible to mention the output html location for dotnet-stryker?

Tags: stryker, stryker-net

I am trying to run mutations over my .NET project using stryker and indeed able to do it successfully using the command :-

```
dotnet stryker -s Assessment.sln -p <Absolute path to csproj file>
```

I want to specify the target location where the html report should be generated. Currently I am getting it under

```
<Project test dir>/StrykerOutput/<timestamp>/reports/mutation-report.html
```

Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, regretfully it's not possible, you would need to copy it manually.

You can see the list of configuration options [here](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/Configuration/).